# Get index of element in list of elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><button></button></li>
  <li><button></button></li>
</ul>
```

On the following code "this" reefers to list with class "nav":

```
  $.fn.slider = function () {

    $(this).each(function () {

      var $this = $(this);

      var $pages = $this.find("button");

      $pages.on("click", function (element) {             
        console.log($(element).index($pages));
      });
```

I get the output: -1 on console.log

Basically I am trying to get the index of the button in the list ...

Why does this happens?

Comment: `element` isn't what you think it is, you're passing the event object. try `$pages.index( this );` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `index()` method and pass `this` as parameter to the clicked button to get the value:

```js
$(document).on("click", "ul > li > button", function() {
     console.log($("ul > li > button").index(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><button>Button 1</button></li>
  <li><button>Button 2</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the `index` of the button is getting the index of `<li>` since you have one `button` in each `li`. Just like this:

```js
$('ul.nav li').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><button>1</button></li>
  <li><button>2</button></li>
  <li><button>3</button></li>
 </ul>
```

The `index()` function 'counts' elements only in the particular parent (not on the whole page)